# Google Play Services LocationClient returns null

Tags: android, google-api, location, google-play-services

I am new to android and I want to get the current location for which I am referring to the link http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html which shows the use of Google Play Services.

To start with I have downloaded the sample LocationUpdates from the above link and I am using an emulator(AVD with target Google API Inc,API Level 17,Platform 4.2.2).

I am trying to get the current Location and it returns null.It uses LocationCLient and makes a call mLocationClient.getLastLocation().

Check is made if Google Play Services are available by using GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this); here it returns 0(success).

I have enabled the Location access in the emulator:Wifi and GPS Satellites.

Please help me to know what is mising so that I get the current location.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try opening Google Maps on the emulator once so that the Google Play Services can update, then  enable "Access Location" from the Google Settings application under "Google Location".

After doing this I was able to manually push GPS-locations to the device using the emulator controls and accessing them from the LocationClient.

Answer (score 0):

If both your WiFi and GPS services are enabled,is your device actually connected to WiFi too? If not, your WiFi service won't be working, and the location provider will fall back to GPS. GPS will not be quick enough to get your location which lead the value (getLastLocation()) to be null sometimes.